# Getting dynamically generated session variables

Tags: php, arrays, session, dynamically-generated

Trying to get value of dynamically generated session variable. I passed an array of keys to a function but function returns this string:

```
['key1']['key2']['key3']
```

and not as an interpolated session value.

Code:

```
// Sample $_SESSION superglobal
Array
(
    [key1] => Array
    (
        [key2] => Array
        (
            [key3] => 'data to return'
        )
    )
)

// Function
public function session_data( $variables = array() )
{
    // Set variables
    $_dataArray = null;
    $_dataArray = "['" . implode( "']['", $variables ) . "']";

    // Return
    return $_SESSION{$_dataArray};
}

// Call function
var str = session_data( array('key1', 'key2', 'key3') );
echo str;  // Echoes ['key1']['key2']['key3'] instead of 'data to return'
```

What am I doing incorrectly? I thought the curly braces around $_dataArray would generate the following, $_SESSION['key1']['key2']['key3'], interpolate, and return the value (e.g. 'data to return').

Comment: `session_data( array('key1', key2', 'key3') );` `'` missed? is it typo?

Comment: Yes, missed the '. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$_dataArray` generation doesn't make any sense. What you are trying to do (`$_SESSION['key1']['key2']['key3']`) is a simple array:

```
$array = [
    'key1' => [
        'key2' => [
            'key3' => 'Your data'
        ]
    ]
];

$_SESSION = $array;

echo $_SESSION['key1']['key2']['key3'] . PHP_EOL; // Echoes 'Your data'
```

Comment: Yes, but the array passed into the function can be any number of values. I can't just hardcode $_SESSION['key1']['key2']['key3'] because the passed in data can be something like session_data( array('key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4', 'key5', 'key6', 'key7', 'key8', 'key9', 'key10', and so on...) ); Which means I have to account for whatever is passed into the function dynamically.

Comment: You can write function which accepts any number of arguments with [variadics](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) (in PHP5.6+) or [func_get_arg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php). I don't really understand what you want to achieve with this.

Comment: That's the idea as with variadics but I want to access values in the $_SESSION superglobal. By prepending, '$_SESSION' to {$_dataArray} I thought it would execute and return the associated value. Instead, I'm getting the imploded string of keys I passed in originally.

Comment: You can't just prepend `$_SESSION` to `$_dataArray`. This is not how it works. I still don't understand what you want to achieve with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of recursive function like this ::

```
function loop_through($array){
    foreach ($array as $key=> $val){
        if (!is_array($val)) { 
            return $val; 
        } else { 
           return ( loop_through($val) ); 
        } 
    }
}

echo loop_through($array); // echoes 'Your data'
```